# Ruby TkPackage can't find package BWidget (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I am now using Ruby to develop a small tool which requires a GUI. Naturally, I use tk to implement the GUI, which should include a combobox, and my code is like:

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/bwidget'
root = TkRoot.new('height' => 615, 'width' => 205){title 'Window'}
combobox = Tk::BWidget::ComboBox.new(root)
combobox.values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
combobox.place('height' => 25, 'width'  => 100, 'x'   => 10, 'y'   => 10 )
Tk.mainloop
```

However, this does not seem to work, as the Runtime error "Ruby TkPackage can't find package BWidget" prompts each time when I run the program. But I have checked the library, and the bwidget folder could actually be found in the tkextlib folder.

Anybody know why this does not work?

Comment: I tested here with Ruby version 2.4 and it worked fine. Which Ruby version are you using? Did you install the gem `tk` before trying to require it?

Comment: Thank you, @rodsoars I was using Ruby version 2.0, and changing to Ruby 2.4 did not solve the problem. So I tried installing tk using the "gem install tk" command, which was not successful with an error message "Can't find proper Tcl/Tk libraries. So, can't make tcltklib.so which is required by Ruby/Tk.". Do you have any idea of how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There seems to be missing system packages. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @rodsoars Windows7. And the weird thing is, some of the basic components like button and entry can be used, while some cannot.

Answer (score 3):

With RubyInstaller-2.4.1 it's possible to install tk and the BWidget package per MSYS2. Run the following commands in `cmd` (replace `x86_64` by `i686` when running the 32 bit version of Ruby):

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-bwidget
gem install tk
```

This should add the necessary libraries for `Tk::BWidget`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the installation tutorial for Windows in the [official site](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html), you should install Ruby from the [RubyInstaller site](https://rubyinstaller.org/), making sure to check the option to include Tk/Tcl support.

If you use RVM, try to reinstall your current Ruby version running `rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0 --with-tcl --with-tk` (assuming Ruby 2.0 is your current version).

Comment: Actually, that was exactly what I did when installing Ruby. I used the installer, and did remember to check the option of Tk/Tcl support, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Hm. Did more research here and, according to this [source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/GUI_Toolkit_Modules/Tk), you should install [ActiveTcl](https://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) too. RubyInstaller installs the Tk binaries, but it still needs ActiveTcl installed beforehand to work.

Comment: Even better, for example  `rvm reinstall 2.6.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthread --with-tk --with-tcl`

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing the bwidget toolkit on your system.

The BWidget toolkit is a high-level widget set for Tcl / Tk (extension widgets for Tcl / Tk). It contains widgets such as progress bars, 3D separators, frames, paned or scrolled windows, button boxes, notebooks or dialogs as well as composite widgets such as combo boxes, spin boxes and tree widgets etc.

In Ubuntu 18.04 I had to install the tcl / tk extension to be able to use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bwidget
```